# VMware виртуальная сеть

Tags: vmware

Всем привет, изучаю системное администрирование, хочу в VMWare Workstation создать виртуальную сеть. Вот как я вижу это. Хочу создать несколько компов на обычной винде + windows server для AD + несколько машин на Linux для настройки proxy, firewall, dhcp, dns. При этом, хочу контролировать эту сеть в плане того что бы машинам на обычной windows ограничивать доступ на разные интернет ресурсы и т.п. может можете подсказать как правильно настроить эту сеть в VM для этих хотелок.

Comment: Все интерфейсы в любой VMNet, кроме 0,1,8 - соответственно виртуалки будут как подключенные к одному свичу. Машина с выходом в Инет - внешним интерфейсом в VMNet8. Вообще всё это в справке к Варе очень подробно расписано... https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/17/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-0CE1AE01-7E79-41BB-9EA8-4F839BE40E1A.html

Comment: Спасибо за обратную связь